# P2V fails on Windows 7 machine with vmware vCenter Converter

Tags: windows-7, osx-lion, virtualization, vmware-fusion, vcenter

Today I started to convert my physical x64 Windows 7 laptop to using the tool vmware vCenter Standalone converter for my mac book pro.

The progress failed at the level of %98.

The error is :

```
FAILED: Unable to find the system volume, reconfiguration is not possible.
```

I think there is a trick to achieve but I couldn't make it.

Can you help me please?